# radbusyindicator not working properly

Tags: windows-phone-7, telerik

I am using radbusyindicator while the data is loading. But its not working properly.
Below is the code

```
      public MainPage()
       {
          InitializeComponent();
          DataContext = App.Model;   
          this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
            radbusyIndicator.IsRunning = true;
            SampleData.Data.getInfo();
            SampleData.Data.getData();

        }));

        radbusyIndicator.IsRunning = false;   
    }
```

What happens if I do like this is that the indicator keeps running. Looks like the control goes to dispatcher after radbusyIndicator.IsRunning = false;   is executed.
But I dont know how to disable it once the data is loaded. Tried many ways, But couldnt make it work. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Most likely `IsRunning = false` will be executed before the dispatcher method is called (a race condition ... actually it will probably never do getInfo and getData before the last line). You need to put the `IsRunning = false` inside the dispatcher callback

Comment: I do not no if this is allowed, but did you try to call radbusyIndicator.IsRunning = false; under the Action() method?? after the SampleData.Data.getData();

Answer (score 0):

The dispatcher callback will in probably 100% of cases fire after the

`radbusyIndicator.IsRunning = false`

line.

Try the following instead:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = App.Model;   
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        radbusyIndicator.IsRunning = true;
        SampleData.Data.getInfo();
        SampleData.Data.getData();
        radbusyIndicator.IsRunning = false;   
    }));
}
```

This is because the very act of marshalling the call to the UI thread takes some CPU cycles and the original `radbusyIndicator.IsRunning = false` is pretty much the next line to run.

It doesn't matter anyway, as you will either get a brief flicker of busy indicator, or it will remain on screen forever, since you don't hide it *after* the work is done, you are hiding it immediately

Edit:

Yeah ignore that last one - realised that it won't work:

If the methods are async, the indicator will hide immediately, if they aren't async, the UI thread will be blocked whilst they do work

If your methods are sync you need to do the work on another thread and marshall UI updates to the UI thread using the dispatcher

You can use `BackgroundWorker` to do work on another thread:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        radbusyIndicator.IsRunning = true;
    }));

    SampleData.Data.getInfo();
    SampleData.Data.getData();

    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        radbusyIndicator.IsRunning = false;   
    }));
}
```

Then in your constructor:

```
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. tried your code, but it doesnt show the indicator now. may be it comes and disappears soon

Comment: Probably because all methods are now on the UI thread and you are locking the thread with the work you are doing on it - I'll update the answer

Comment: Why don't you set the RadBusyIndicator's IsBusy property in XAML to true and toggle it off after the data has been retrieved.